# How to block remote access connection in java web application

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I want this solution for the examination java web application project, to make sure that the student is just taking the exam on his machine only.

So we want to block all the remote access software when the students access our examination portal and log in to the exam. Using javascript or JSP we wanted to detect the remote access is there or not.

Does anyone know how to detect if a client of a web application uses remote access?

Comment: If you are asking if your web app can prevent the student from using *their* machine to connect to somewhere else during the exam, I think it is impossible.  And besides, they could just use a second machine, or someone else's mobile phone, etcetera.  If you are asking something else, please clarify ... because I can't figure out what (else) you could mean.

Comment: What we want is that no one should be able to access the student's machine during the exam.

Comment: That is what I thought you meant.  It is not possible ... unless you take the student's PC and **physically** disconnect it from the internet.  (And also put it in a Faraday cage to block wireless access.)

Comment: *"Does anyone know how to detect if a client of a web application uses remote access?"* - That is also not possible.